# Using zsh and mcports. Command not found

Tags: terminal, zsh, macports

I installed macports but I use zsh. What should I modify in the .zshrc file to get it to look for macports? I think macports is located in /opt/local/bin/port

Answer (score 9):

if you're using zsh and you installed using the package:

open `~/.zshrc`

go to `export PATH = ...` under `# User Configuration`

add `/opt/local/bin` to the end of `export PATH`

restart terminal

type `port version` to see if it's installed

Comment: You can also add the path to /etc/paths file in mac to store all paths instead of doing export PATH

Answer (score 2):

Just add  /opt/local/bin to the path. [Shell guide](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Guide/zshguide02.html#l24) gives details of editing path

e.g.

```
typeset -U path
path=(/opt/local/bin $path)
```

Note guide suggests ~/.zshenv as the correct startup file for this. But Apple's default /etc/zshrc messes the path order up so stay with editing ~/.zshrc for PATH

Answer (score 2):

If `port` still isn't recognized after adding `opt/local/bin` and restarting your terminal, look in your `.zshrc` to see if the line specifying `export PATH=...` is commented out - by default, mine was.

Comment: Good suggestion, export PATH sure is the default.